# How can I drag draggables outside a listview while stil able to scroll the listview?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of cards and I want each card to be draggable. The list is scrolling horizontally.

But the problem is when I fill the list with draggables I cannot scroll the list anymore. I want to place the draggable card somewhere outside the list. So a ReorderableListView is not what I am looking for. How would I do this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:fun_application/business_logic/state/concrete/the_arena_view_controller.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:random_color/random_color.dart';

class TheArenaView extends StatelessWidget {
  TheArenaView() {
    Get.lazyPut<RandomColor>(() => RandomColor());
    Get.lazyPut<TheArenaViewController>(() => TheArenaViewController());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[Flexible(flex: 7, child: draggableTargetArea()), Flexible(flex: 3, child: cardList())],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget draggableTargetArea() {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.black,
    );
  }

  Widget cardList() {
    return ListView.separated(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: 100,
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(
        width: 10.0,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Draggable(
          feedback: cardSlot(),
          child: card(),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget cardSlot() {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      width: 150,
      color: Colors.grey,
    );
  }

  Widget card() {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      width: 150,
      color: Get.find<RandomColor>().randomColor(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `affinity: Axis.vertical` to my draggales fixed it

```
return Draggable(
  affinity: Axis.vertical,
  feedback: cardSlot(),
  child: card()
);
```

Now I can horizontally scroll my list and vertically drag my cards.